# Matplotlib: plot indicating the precision of measurements

Tags: error-handling

I have some data with some margin of error and am using numpy arrays to plot that data. Assuming the precision is, let's say, 0.05 or 0.03grams, then the data will be something like

[4.0 $\pm$ 0.05, 3.05 $\pm$ 0.03]

How can I show this on my plot (either on the x axis or the y axis. If it's both, even better)?

I use pyplot and my OS is macOS

Comment: Can you use error bars? See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) and this [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/errorbar_demo_features.html). Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I think this pretty much solves my question, as simple as it seems. Should I answer to my own question? (I just read your profile)

Comment: Yes, please. Try to make it self-contained, so users don't need to follow links (unlike my comment).

Comment: It was just downvoted, so I think I'll just delete it. It was a very easy question anyways

Comment: @EvaristeGD Or you can answer your own question and mark the answer correct ... so that it might come useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the `matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar` class.

From [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/errorbar_demo_features.html) in the documentation:

```
# example error bar values that vary with x-position
error = 0.1 + 0.2 * x

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
ax0.errorbar(x, y, yerr=error, fmt='-o')
ax0.set_title('variable, symmetric error')
```

Acknowledgments: Thanks to [Emre](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/381/emre)!